# Understanding Windows Process Memory Layout

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management

I find many blogs and documents explaining process memory layout. All of them describe a memory layout of following kind:
[image]
But when I look at the VMMap tool in windows, I find pages of stack, heap etc... mixed up!
For example:
[image]

I have following questions:

1. Can some one explain why are these images not coherent? Where am I going wrong?
2. When I use `VirtualAllocEx()`, in VMMap, a region gets marked as private memory. Is it heap or stack or memory mapping segment?

Comment: Heap is inside of memory allocated by VirtualAllocEx which is purely virtual. Read this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx

Comment: not coherent how exactly?

Comment: @FrankThomas, In the first picture, the stack is placed at higher addresses and heap at the lower addresses. Heap doesn't come in between stack addresses. But the VMMap shows stack as well as heap mixed up.

Comment: well, first off, your top image is an Linux process, not windows.

Comment: Physical storage allocation is strictly up to the operating system – any physical page can be designated for any purpose.  Likewise the virtual storage space of any process might contain things like memory-mapped file windows.

Comment: Nominated for re-opening. It is completely clear to me what the question is, and what the answer is.

Comment: The first answer is that the first diagram is simply not applicable to Windows. Not even to NT 3.1 on x86. It is not applicable to VMS either. It appears to be a variant of something that was probably drawn regarding Unix in the 1970s. Note that there is not even allowance for things like thread-local storage or per-thread stacks! Just ignore it, and be amused that it's still being copied.

Comment: The second answer is "none of the above". When you use VirtualAllocEx with the _COMMIT option you are creating new virtual address space. It does not come out of existing heap, stack, or memory mapping space. Nor is there any such thing as a region pre-designated for e.g. memory mapping. Each new allocation is created from unallocated virtual address space and there is no reason for all the memory mappings, all of the heaps, etc., to be adjacent. Oh, and by the way, none of those are "segments". The entire "segment" concept is obsolete.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan, Thanks for your answers. With the randomization mechanisms like ASLR, it makes sense to me. But, if the stack needs to grow beyond the allocated space, is more memory going to be allocated at random location? If so, how will the discontinuity be handled? (I mean, `push reg` in intel always decrements `esp` and will not be aware of any discontinuities. 
__Can you also suggest a resource to deep dive into this?__

Comment: A 1 MB region (by default; this can be overridden) of v.a.s. is _reserved_ for each thread's user mode stack; a few pages at its high-address end are _committed_, making them accessible. If the thread's stack usage would exceed the committed size, additional pages are committed as needed. If this would exceed the original reserved size, the attempt fails and this raises an exception. There is also a much smaller, nonpageable stack in kernel space, used while the thread is in kernel mode. Details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/thread-stack-size

Comment: As for memory management in general on Windows, see, of course, _Windows Internals_ by Solomon, Russinovich, _et al_. A very deep dive on the memory manager is in a book called _What Makes It Page?_, available on Amazon.

Comment: btw, if you liked my answer, you could vote to re-open with reason e.g. "question produced the answer I was looking for in the comments; answerer should be allowed to post it as an actual answer". Just a suggestion.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan, I want to reopen the question as well as upvote your comment in the form of answer. But I don't find an option to request to reopen. Maybe because I'm the author of the question.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case.  I think that if  a mod doesn't understand a question the mod should at least consider deferring to the opinion of those who do.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Regarding the claim "It appears to be a variant of something that was probably drawn regarding Unix in the 1970s.": the diagram depicts the layout of a process in virtual memory on x86 Linux. If you look at the left-hand side of the diagram, it indicates 4GB address space. If you look at the right side, the variable names listed there are defined in Linux kernel header files (e.g. `end_code`, `start_data` from [mm_types.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/mm_types.h)). The blog post the image was taken from was written in 2009.